# How to load webforms in a windows based installer?

Tags: iframe, installation, html

I want to know how to load an webpage into a installer just like the below example:

[image: Example of a form with email subscription]

How this can be done? And, which installer in the market supports this feature? I have tried NSIS and SetupFactory, but can't found it.

Also is it possible that if someone doesn't fill out the field(s) mentioned in webpage, the "Next" button remain disable?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please somebody help me on this. I need to know this urgently.

Comment: I've made a [`project`](http://code.google.com/p/inno-web-browser/source/browse/#svn/trunk) that can embed web browser into the InnoSetup (I know it's out of your request, but InnoSetup is the only I know).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If you don't mind, can I see those project samples you're talking about? I'd be grateful.

Comment: Sure, simply download InnoSetup from [`here`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/download.php/is-unicode.exe), install it and copy the [`Example.iss`](http://code.google.com/p/inno-web-browser/source/browse/trunk/Example.iss) script with the [`WebBrowser.dll`](http://code.google.com/p/inno-web-browser/source/browse/trunk/WebBrowser.dll) library into the same, writeable folder (doesn't matter where) open the newly installed `Inno Setup Compiler` open the `Example.iss` script and press F9. You will run the setup where on the second page (after welcome page) will be a web browser control embedded.

Comment: Excellent! It worked, but the only downfall is that I can't use "B" and "N" key on keyboard while filling a text field since, they're reserved for "Back" and "Next" button respectively. Can you fix that?

Comment: 10x Tlama for this feature, i tried it but I receive the following run time error - "Cannot Import dll:<utf8>c:users\Elram~1.vas\Appdata\Local\Temp\is-etge.tmp\webbrowser.dll" do you know how to solve it?